# infinitive with to as a noun modifier

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis, infinitive-clauses

> I have **a paper to write before class**.

I can say this, if I'm not mistaken, this way:

> I have **a paper *which is* to be written before class**.

What has happened here? What is the name of this?

Another example:

> **The inherent desire to develop that technique** caused him to spend 11 years on it.

Here this can be said in this way:

> **The inherent desire *(which was to/in order to)* develop that technique** caused him to spend 11 years on it.

Could you give me a link for further study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... a paper to write  /  a paper to be written
>   ... a desire to develop that technique

These are two very different *NOUN TO VERB* constructions.

The first "derives" from a clause in which *NOUN* is the Patient of *VERB* (its Direct Object in the first, active version, its Subject in the second, passive version). This, as you correctly observe, may be paraphrased with a relative clause   *which is to write*  /  *which is to be written*.

The second, however, derives from a construction in which *NOUN* is originally a verb taking an infinitive clause as its complement:

> I desire apples. I desire a fulfilling life. I desire to develop that technique.

Your proposed relative clauses don’t work there, because they disrupt this particular syntactic relationship: now the noun *desire* lacks its necessary complement.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to sound extremely formal and educated, just use the infinitive.

> I have a paper which is to be written before class.

Would be said to a boss that you've never met before when you're trying to get a day off to write the paper, possibly over email, for example.

> I have a paper to write before class.

Would be used pretty much everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure of all the details,
but I believe that the infinitive is not modifying the noun. 
Rather, the noun is the (direct) object of the verb (infinitive).

> I have a paper to write before class.

=

> I have to write a paper before class.

It seems that “have” is being used to mean something like “need”. 
Note that this construct can work without the noun object:

> I have to eat.

You can see this mentioned in this EL&U question:
[Omitting the last “to” in “All {I need to / have to / must} do is (to?) do something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/122277/26083). 
The answer to [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/330/26083) addresses the large issue,
but, curiously, doesn’t say much about “have”.

Comment: Then what you do think about "Is there anything to drink?" ?

Comment: It still seems like “anything” might be the object of the verb.